# How to create data for expandable list adapter in a smart way

Tags: android, arraylist

Experts,

Below code is to get data for ExpandableListAdapter. I have problem about the **List temp**.

Let say I have below data in db:

Header A, Child 123,111

Header B, child 456,444

Header C, child 789,777

The result I expect is:

expListChild.put(A, 123,111); //(actual result: expListChild.put(A, 123,111,456,444,789,777)

expListChild.put(B, 456,444); //(actual result: expListChild.put(B, 123,111,456,444,789,777)

expListChild.put(C, 789,777); //(actual result: expListChild.put(C, 123,111,456,444,789,777)

I don't know how to do, I've been thought of use temp1, temp2, but I don't know how many rows in Cursor cHeader .

Could you help me please? Thanks.
I guess the problem is I don't know how to create a series of variables.

```
List<String> expListHeader = new ArrayList<>();
HashMap<String, List<String>> expListChild = new HashMap<>();
List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();

void xxx() {
    Cursor cHeader = db.rawQuery("XXX", null);
    cHeader.moveToFirst();
    while (cHeader.moveToNext())
    {
        String headerStr = cHeader.getString(0);
        expListHeader.add(headerStr);

        Cursor cChild = db.rawQuery("XXX", null);
        cChild.moveToFirst();
        while (cChild.moveToNext()) {
            String childStr = cChild.getString(0);
            temp.add(childStr);
        }
        cChild.close();

        expListChild.put(headerStr, temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Got stuck here, really need help...

Comment: You should use pojo for this and set and get all data with this pojo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `temp.clear()` before `Cursor cChild = db.rawQuery("XXX", null);` to release all objects in your temp list.

**Updated (since I was stupid)**

List expListHeader = new ArrayList<>();
HashMap> expListChild = new HashMap<>();

```
void xxx() {
    Cursor cHeader = db.rawQuery("XXX", null);
    cHeader.moveToFirst();
    while (cHeader.moveToNext()) {
        String headerStr = cHeader.getString(0);
        expListHeader.add(headerStr);

        List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cChild = db.rawQuery("XXX", null);
        cChild.moveToFirst();
        while (cChild.moveToNext()) {
            String childStr = cChild.getString(0);
            temp.add(childStr);
        }
        cChild.close();

        expListChild.put(headerStr, temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: In that case, only get expListChild.put(C, 789,777); cannot get A, B

Comment: Sorry, that was my typo. Fixed answer

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought of at the beginning, but it would become (A, null),(B, null), (C, 789,777). It seems expListChild.put(xx,temp) only links temp, not copy temp's value to expListChild, any change in temp would affect expListChild even after the .put statement.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a stupid. Hard work ate my brain. I will update my answer

Comment: AMAZING, a BIG THANK YOU!

Comment: If it's not hard for you, then, please, mark my answer as right.